# Razor Pages anchor tag generating incorrect URL

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I am attempting to create a simple web application using razor pages. The rendered anchor tag for `Create` is not being generated correctly.

```xml
<a href>Create</a>
```

My application seems to not have `/Facility/Create` as a valid URL even if I manually go there. Is there something else that I am suppose to be doing to get the anchor tag to render as

```xml
<a href="/Facility/Create">Create</a>
```

and for the application to know about `/Facility/Create`.

```xml
@page
@model IndexModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<h1>Facilities</h1>
<form method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var facility in Model.Facilities)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@facility.Name</td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page="Edit" asp-route-id="@facility.Id">edit</a>
                    <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="delete"
                            asp-route-id="@facility.Id">
                        delete
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a asp-page="/Facility/Create">Create</a>
</form>
```

[image: structure]

Comment: Which Index page is the above shown markup belong to? *Pages/Index.cshtml* or *Pages/Facility/Index.cshtml*?

Comment: @Nkosi - This is the `/Pages/Facility/Index.cshtml`

Comment: In that case `<a asp-page="Create">Create</a>` should work. If not, check that the actual *.cshtml* file is recognized by the project and not excluded when built. In many cases clearing and rebuilding the project solves the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi - I have tried `<a asp-page="Create">`, `<a asp-page="./Create">`, and `<a asp-page="/Facility/Create">` --- I have also done a clean and rebuild and checked to make sure it is included in the build.  I do have a `.g.cs` file in the `/obj`

Comment: @Nkosi - Here is a repo that reproduces the problem for me - https://github.com/bdparrish/razor-pages-bug

Comment: I check the *.csproj* file and it includes `<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Pages\Facility\" />
  </ItemGroup>`. Remove that, recompile, and it should now be able to see the pages in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tooling issue based on the IDE version being used, that may be corrupting the *.csproj* file.

The provided repo example has the following *.csproj*

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Pages\Facility\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In my research I came across the following

> `<Folder Include="..." />` just represents an empty folder inside the project. It doesn't include any file under the folder to the project.

In creating the folder the project added the node to the project file, but did not remove it after files were added. So the razor pages added under that folder were not being included at compile time and this caused the described issues at run time.

Suggest removing the node from the *.csproj*, as all files in the project folder are included/embedded/compiled by default unless specifically opted out in the project file.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

after recompiling the project, the missing pages will be available and provide the expected behavior.

Finally check to make sure that available patches and updates are applied to the IDE being used.